Is there a way to have clang-format align short function bodies?
I'd like to have clang format align consecutive short functions, aligning various parts of those functions. Is this possible?
I have this:
 DataType                      GetDataType( ) const { return m_dataType; }
 const std::string&            GetMessageId( ) const { return m_messageId; }
 const std::string&            GetFrom( ) const { return m_from; }
 const std::string&            GetText( ) const { return m_text; }
 const std::string&            GetReferenceId( ) const { return m_referenceId; }
 const ::common::StringVector& GetToList( ) const { return m_toList; }
 const ::common::StringVector& GetMediaUrls( ) const { return m_mediaUrls; }

and I'd like it formatted as this:
 DataType                      GetDataType( )    const { return m_dataType;    }
 const std::string&            GetMessageId( )   const { return m_messageId;   }
 const std::string&            GetFrom( )        const { return m_from;        }
 const std::string&            GetText( )        const { return m_text;        }
 const std::string&            GetReferenceId( ) const { return m_referenceId; }
 const ::common::StringVector& GetToList( )      const { return m_toList;      }
 const ::common::StringVector& GetMediaUrls( )   const { return m_mediaUrls;   }

I've tried adjusting penalties as well as alignments, but have been unable to fully align it.
